# Select multiple values from dropdown using Macros in EPPLUS

Tags: excel, vba, .net-core, epplus

I have a column named as **Skills** in my excel sheet and I want to select multiple values from that dropdown. I am currently using Epplus to generate the csv dynamically with that dropdown. I wanted to know if there is a way in Epplus with which I can use Macros Code to select multiple values from that dropdown.

[image: Dropdown List]

Edit 1 : VBA Code used from [here](https://trumpexcel.com/select-multiple-items-drop-down-list-excel/)

[image: VBA Code used here]

Comment: Not sure what you are asking.  Do you want to turn on the autofilter and select specific items?  If so, see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32723483/adding-a-specific-autofilter-on-a-column/32766493#32766493  If thats not it, post code and screen shots of what you are trying to do.

Comment: @ErnieS I have added an image. I am pre-populating this dropdown list. I want to select multiple values from this dropdown (comma separated). For eg : On selecting .Net and React, the row text must be like (.Net,React)

Comment: So it looks like you need to use VBA code?  That can be done, see this:  https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus/wiki/VBA  If you get stuck, post your code and we can take a look.

Comment: @ErnieS I tried the following VBA code but it is still not working. Any idea why ?

Comment: You need top post all of your code that you are using to generate the file otherwise people can only guess.  I suggest you create a simple unit test to get as close as you can and then post that test.